# How do I install NTFS-3G from source?

Tags: applications

I want to install the latest version of NTFS-3G on my Yosemite box. The latest version (as of this writing) is 2014.2.15 available [here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/). However, only the source code is available and there aren't any instructions on how to compile or install it.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The Mac link is always separate…

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/
has a link to
http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/